# How to put a Stack as a child of CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I am using a CustomScrollView. I have added a few slivers in it but one of my children has to be a stack which has a list as on of its two children. I tried using SliverToBoxAdapter but that makes the list in the stack non scrollable which is the obvious behaviour. Is there a way to to write some kind of SliverToSliverAdapter? I tried reading the SliverPadding but its looks too complicated for me to understand. Below is my code:

```
  CustomScrollView(
        key: PageStorageKey<String>(name),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverOverlapInjector(
              handle:
                  NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: pink),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return buildSongRow(songs[index]);
                  },
                  itemCount: songs.length,
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

`Stack` widget use parent's size by default. While parent widget is `CustomScrollView` that decide it's size mean, it will get infinite height. To solve this issue, we can wrap `Stack` with `SizedBox(height:x)`.

Next issue comes on `Stack` about scrolling and widget visibility. Widget render prioritize bottom to top and same for the scroll event. While `Container(height:50)` is the first child of `Stack`, it will be paint behind `ListView` and in this case we can have full-scroll event on `ListView`.

We can move `Container<height:50>` at the bottom to paint it over `ListView`. In this case, scroll-event won't work on `Container<h:50>` portion.

We can wrap `Container<h:50>` and `ListView` with `SizedBox` by providing `height` and use `Align` or `Positioned` widget to place them on `Stack`. Also, we can increase `itemCount+1` and use an empty `SizedBox(height:50)`(on index 0) that will take same amount of height as `Container(height:50)` and help to view only for 1st time on `Stack`.

I am using `LayoutBuilder` to get the size/constraints of screen.

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            const SliverAppBar(
              title: Text("Stack On CustomScrollView"),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .3, // used by stack
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        // dont need to use sizedBox here, height is fixed by container's height:50
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: const Text("Stack Child: Container<height: 50>"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight * .3 - 50,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 4,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            height: 50,
                            color: index.isEven
                                ? Colors.deepOrange
                                : Colors.deepPurple,
                            child: Text("ListViewItem:$index"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  ...List.generate(
                    44,
                    (index) => Container(
                      height: 100,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      color: index.isEven ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.blueGrey,
                      child: Text("SliverList $index"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: There are two scroll-event needed to be handle while inner-scroll end if you wish to.